# B.register is not a function in fusioncharts

Tags: fusioncharts

Im getting an error of

```
TypeError: B.register is not a function
at /Test/node_modules/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts.js:6:125
```

I am using fusioncharts installed via npm and have reverted to their guide on rendering charts via npm [here](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/installing-via-npm-and-bower/rendering-charts-via-npm.html). Following step by step the error comes when trying including

```
require("fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts")(FusionCharts);
```

Performing a search in the fusioncharts.charts.js file shows me they do have a `B.register` function inside. Is their guide wrong and missing a step, or is this a bug. I can display the chart using HTML fine, the js implementation is having hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts is not completely ES6 compatible as of now so you have to use webpack bundler to render the charts via npm.